# Bluetooth not working properly on dual booting

Tags: dual-boot, bluetooth

Today, after dual booting Ubuntu with Windows 10, everything worked properly except 2 things,

1. Bluetooth
2. Microphone

When I looked up for 'Bluetooth issues in dual booting' I found out that Linux and Windows use different Mac Addresses for Bluetooth settings.
So, I followed up the tutorial and changed the Bluetooth mac address for my headphones.

But still, the headphone would connect, and then disconnect again on both Ubuntu and Windows.
This is a very big problem for me since I keep my headphones on almost the whole day.
So, I wanted to know if there are any fixes to this issue.
If there are no particular fixes, will uninstalling Bluetooth help?

If either of them is possible, please let me know how to do it.
(I'm very new to Ubuntu, so please bare with me)
Any help is largely appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, when dual-booting, disabling Fast Startup in Windows is a must, so you should start with that properly shutdown Windows before booting Ubuntu. Then, if the problem persists and on both OSes it's unlikely the problem is OS or software related.

Comment: Will try disabling it.